# Given two sets $A$ and $B$ in a metric space, if $A \subset B$, then cl($A$) $\subset$ cl($B$).

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I'm self studying analysis and was reading through Rudin's Principles of Mathematical Analysis when I thought of this statement that looks true, which I've decided to prove. I was wondering if my proof is correct and rigorous enough.

**Statement: Given two sets $A$ and $B$ in a metric space, if $A \subset B$, then cl($A$) $\subset$ cl($B$).**

**My Proof:** Pick an arbitrary $x \in$ cl($A$) and consider the neighborhood around $x$ for some arbitrary radius $r >0$. Since $x$ is either a limit point or a member of $A$, the constructed neighborhood must intersect $A$ and therefore $B$.

There are now two cases, 1) if $x \in B$ or 2) if $x \notin B$.

If 1) holds, then we are done since $x \in$ cl($B$). 
If 2) holds, then $x$ is a limit point of $B$ since the arbitrarily constructed neighborhood intersects $B$. Thus $x \in$ cl($B$).

Comment: Just show the closure of the unions contains the union of the closures.

Comment: Note the closure of A is the set of all points distance zero from A. Well if they have distance zero to A they have distance zero to B, are in the closure of B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the right idea, but it's simpler than you do: a point $x$ belongs to $\operatorname{cl}(A)$ if and only if, for every neighborhood $U$ of $x$, $U\cap A\ne\emptyset$.

If $x\in\operatorname{cl}(A)$ and $U$ is a neighborhood of $x$, then $U\cap A\ne\emptyset$ and therefore also $U\cap B\ne\emptyset$.

No need to distinguish between members and limit points.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using the following, which you may have already learned in class

**Lemma** The closure of a set, $\overline{S}$, is the intersection of all closed sets containing $S$.

From this we see that if $C$ is closed and contains $B$ then as $A\subseteq B$ we have $A\subseteq C$, hence $\text{cl}(A)\subseteq\text{cl}(B)$ by the lemma.